# Mongoose ValidationError makes Express Server crashed

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, joi

I have struggled with this problem for many days.

Whenever I make an invalid POST request, it throws me an Error. Sounds good but when I cancel that request, the server closes to???

This is an invalid request.

```
{
    "title": "Test from Postman",
    "description": "Test from Postman",
    "time": "2021-05-12",
    "status": "abc"
}
```

This is the error I get.

[image]

You guys can look through my repo [here](https://github.com/ngthuongdoan/knowledge-review/tree/overview/overview/server). Maybe the error comes from mongoose validation

Thank you.

Comment: Your server crash because you didn't handle the error. Put your code in try/catch block and handle error inside catch will solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please show me what files need to try/catch? I've already used these files and figure out that the error comes from mongoose validation.

Comment: For example: `const createTodo: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try { ... } catch (e) { ... }
};`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The issue was that I was catching the error in two places: one in the server file and one in the app file. Removing the catch error from the server file allowed the error to be caught in the app file, and handled in the app file correctly.

Wrong code:

```
// server file

const create = (person) => {
  const request = axios.post(baseUrl, person)
  return request
  .then((response) => response.data)
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)) // this is the problem
}
```

Right code:

```
// server file

const create = (person) => {
  const request = axios.post(baseUrl, person)
  return request
  .then((response) => response.data)
  // the catch line has been removed here because the error is caught elsewhere
}
```